# What could cause Ubuntu to start loosing devices (12.10, T420)

Tags: wireless, drivers, mouse, devices

I recently upgraded Ubuntu on a laptop where it had been running flawlessly for some time.

It's a dualboot setup and all of the devices work fine under windows 7 however the wifi did not work correctly and my USB mouse was not recognized this morning after I plugged it in.

I'm looking in `dmesg` and `/var/log/` and don't even see the wireless (Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 AGN).  Does this mean it's just not supported by the kernel I'm running?

If I boot my older kernel from the boot menu wi-fi works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless device is well-supported. I suspect the driver didn't load automatically for some reason. Let's get it to load:

```
sudo su
echo iwlwifi >> /etc/modules
modprobe iwlwifi
exit
```

You should be all set.